# stream parallel skip - does the order of the chained stream methods make any difference?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
stream.parallel().skip(1)
```

vs

```
stream.skip(1).parallel()
```

This is about Java 8 streams.
Are both of these skipping the 1st line/entry?

The example is something like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Test010 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = 
        "a,b,c\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9\n";

        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(message))){

            AtomicLong cnt = new AtomicLong(1);

            br.lines().parallel().skip(1).forEach(
                s -> {
                    System.out.println(cnt.getAndIncrement() + "->" + s);
                }
            );

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Earlier today, I was sometimes getting the header line "a,b,c" in the lambda expression. This was a surprise since I was expecting to have skipped it already. Now I cannot get that example to work i.e. I cannot get the header line in the lambda expression. So I am pretty confused now, maybe something else was influencing that behavior. Of course this is just an example. In the real world the message is being read from a CSV file. The message is the full content of that CSV file.

Comment: Did you try both of them to find out?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Read the [API note](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-)

Comment: I tried the 1st option and it seems to me (I am pretty sure actually) that I am not skipping the 1st line/entry. I am just skipping some random entry.

Comment: Perhaps you are stumbling upon [“Stream.skip behavior with unordered terminal operation”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30843279/2711488). Check which exact Java version you are using.

Comment: @Andrew While trying them both could prove them to be different, it is useless for determining if they _must_ be the same, which is really what the OP is asking.  He doesn't mean "might it sometimes produce the same result", but "must it produce the same result."  And trying it out doesn't really help with that; you have to appeal to the _specification_.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Yes, that's basically what I meant. I posted an example but now for some reason I cannot get the same behavior I saw earlier today.

Comment: Side note after reading Holger's answer: I think my question is just fine :) not sure why it got quickly downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have two questions in one, the first being whether it makes a difference in writing `stream.parallel().skip(1)` or `stream.skip(1).parallel()`, the second being whether either or both will always skip the first element. See also [“loaded question”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question).

The first answer is that it makes no difference, because specifying a `.sequential()` or `.parallel()` execution policy affects the entire Stream pipeline, regardless of where you place it in the call chain—of course, unless you specify multiple contradicting policies, in which case the last one wins.

So in either case you are requesting a parallel execution which might affect the outcome of the `skip` operation, which is subject of the second question.

The answer is not that simple. If the Stream has no defined encounter order in the first place, an arbitrary element might get skipped, which is a consequence of the fact that there is no “first” element, even if there might be an element you encounter first when iterating over the source.

If you have an ordered Stream, `skip(1)` *should* skip the first element, but this has been laid down only recently. As discussed in [“Stream.skip behavior with unordered terminal operation”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30843279/2711488), chaining an unordered terminal operation had an effect on the `skip` operation in earlier implementations and there was some uncertainty of whether this could even be intentional, as visible in [“Is this a bug in Files.lines(), or am I misunderstanding something about parallel streams?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28259636/2711488), which happens to be close to your code; apparently skipping the first line is a common case.

The final word is that the behavior of earlier JREs is a bug and `skip(1)` on an ordered stream should skip the first element, even when the stream pipeline is executed in parallel and the terminal operation is unordered. The [associated bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8129120) names jdk1.8.0_60 as first fixed version, which I could verify. So if you are using on older implementation, you *might* experience the Stream skipping different elements when using `.parallel()` and the unordered `.forEach(…)` terminal operation. It’s not contradicting if the implementation occasionally skips the expected element, that’s the unpredictability of multi-threading.

So the answer still is that `stream.parallel().skip(1)` and `stream.skip(1).parallel()` have the same behavior, even when being used in earlier versions, as both are equally unpredictable when being used with an unordered terminal operation like `forEach`. They *should* always skip the first element with ordered Streams and when being used with `1.8.0_60` or newer, they do.

Comment: Thanks. So ... is my stream `br.lines()` ordered (the way I create it)? I used 1.8.0_25 btw when I noticed that behavior. What about the case: ordered stream and JVM earlier than 1.8.0_60?

Comment: Yes, `BufferedReader.lines()` returns an ordered Stream. That’s why I said, it *should* work. Still, doing a single `readLine()` call on the `BufferedReader` *before* invoking `lines()` saves you from the costs of a (parallel) `skip` operation and works in all versions. As said, in JREs earlier than 1.8.0_60, you get surprising behavior if the *terminal operation* is unordered, which is the case with `forEach`.

Comment: Ah! Good idea. I didn't think that's possible (to call `readLine` and then to create the stream). I will try all these options. Thanks again for the detailed response.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but `skip(n)` is slower as `n` is larger with a parallel stream.

Here's the API note from [`skip()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#skip-long-):

> While `skip()` is generally a cheap operation on sequential stream pipelines, it can be quite expensive on ordered parallel pipelines, especially for large values of `n`, since `skip(n)` is constrained to skip not just any `n` elements, but the *first `n`* elements in the encounter order. Using an unordered stream source (such as `generate(Supplier)`) or removing the ordering constraint with `BaseStream.unordered()` may result in significant speedups of `skip()` in parallel pipelines, if the semantics of your situation permit. If consistency with encounter order is required, and you are experiencing poor performance or memory utilization with `skip()` in parallel pipelines, switching to sequential execution with `BaseStream.sequential()` may improve performance.

So essentially, if you want better performance with `skip()`, don't use a parellel stream, or use an unordered stream.

---

As for it seeming to not work with parallel streams, perhaps you're actually seeing that the elements are no longer ordered? For example, an output of this code:

```
Stream.of("Hello", "How", "Are", "You?")
    .parallel()
    .skip(1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Is

> Are
>   You?
>   How

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/fFijgK)

This is perfectly fine because `forEach` doesn't enforce the encounter order in a parallel stream. If you want it to enforce the encounter order, use a sequential stream (and perhaps use `forEachOrdered` so that your intent is obvious).

```
Stream.of("Hello", "How", "Are", "You?")
    .skip(1)
    .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

> How
>   Are
>   You?

Comment: Thanks but I don't quite care about performance. I care if I am skipping the 1st entry or some random one.

Comment: @peter.petrov It's not skipping a random one. It still skips the same entries. Could you provide an MCVE of the problem?

Comment: It is, your example is very limited. This question is about encounter order. How do I skip the first one in encounter order?! I think I found the solution, thanks.

Comment: @peter.petrov Can you please share the solution? I'm confused about what's making you think it's not skipping the first one.

Comment: My test and the printouts I added are making me think so. The solution is `forEachOrdered`. I may post an answer myself these days. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @peter.petrov Using `forEachOrdered` sacrifices the benefit of a parallel stream. (this is documented in [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-))  Just use a sequential stream.

Comment: @peter.petrov: recheck whether you are still talking about the same question. Your actual question was, whether it makes a difference if you write `.parallel().skip(1)` or `.skip(1).parallel()`, not how to enforce encounter order.

Comment: @Holger I posted an example.

Comment: @peter.petrov Looking at your example, it seems you're fighting parallel streams and not actually reaping any rewards. You should switch to a sequential stream.

Comment: @4castle I am getting some reward from parallelism since the data is sent in parallel, in the real world that's not a `System.out.println` call there but some send operation. And also... that's not the point here.

Comment: @peter.petrov Okay, that sounds good then as long as the order doesn't matter when you're sending. Glad you got it working!

Comment: @4castle Well, I would be happier if I got it non-working :) I don't understand anything now :) Thanks anyway!