# What is the difference between .foreach and .stream().foreach?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This is a example:
code A:

```
files.forEach(f -> {
    //TODO
});
```

and another code B may use on this way:

```
files.stream().forEach(f -> { });
```

What is the difference between both, with `stream()` and no `stream()`?

Comment: That's not really accurate. Both are semantically equivalent to that, but neither will necessarily have that implementation.

Comment: code A is equals for(File f : files)

Comment: code B should be used when there are some Intermediate operations (map, skip, concat, substream, distinct, filter, sorted, limit, peek..)  else it is  suboptimal.  thanks guys!

Answer (score 27):

Practically speaking, they are mostly the same, but there is a small semantic difference.

Code A is defined by `Iterable.forEach`, whereas code B is defined by `Stream.forEach`. The definition of `Stream.forEach` allows for the elements to be processed in any order -- even for sequential streams. (For parallel streams, `Stream.forEach` will very likely process elements out-of-order.)

`Iterable.forEach` gets an Iterator from the source and calls `forEachRemaining()` on it. As far as I can see, all current (JDK 8) implementations of `Stream.forEach` on the collections classes will create a Spliterator built from one of the source's Iterators, and will then call `forEachRemaining` on that Iterator -- just like `Iterable.forEach` does. So they do the same thing, though the streams version has some extra setup overhead.

However, in the future, it's possible that the streams implementation could change so that this is no longer the case.

(If you want to guarantee ordering of processing streams elements, use `forEachOrdered()` instead.)

Comment: Upvoted for potential change of the implementation may break the current contract

Comment: Surprisingly, the `default` implementation of `Iterable.forEach` does not call `forEachRemaining` on the `Iterator`; it iterates using a for-each loop. The default `Stream.forEach` will call `forEachRemaining` on the `Spliterator` which will end up calling `Iterator.forEachRemaining` unless `Iterable.spliterator()` has been overridden (which most JRE provided `Collection`s do). So even for Collections where `collection.forEach(…)` and `collection.stream().forEach(…)` do basically the same, they end up in different code doing it. But for certain `Collection`s there is a significant difference.

Comment: A notable difference exist for `Vector` and the collections returned by the `Collections.synchronized…` methods as their `forEach` implementations will be `synchronized` while calling `stream().forEach(…)` requires manual synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in terms of semantics, though the direct implementation without `stream` is *probably* slightly more efficient.

Comment: Actually, there *are* differences in term of semantics, e.g. the ordering guarantees (or the absence of them in the `Stream.forEach` case).

Answer (score -3):

Both approaches uses the terminal operation `Iterable.forEach`, but the version with `.stream()` also unnecessarily creates a `Stream` object representing the List. While there is no difference, it is suboptimal.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't correct. The code A is indeed `Iterable.forEach`, but code B is `Stream.forEach` which is not guaranteed to process the elements in any particular order, even for sequential streams.

Comment: @Stuart: That is an API detail, whereas StreamSupport uses underlying Iterable.forEach for streams of Iterable (arrays excluded) since JDK 8. Therefore, your concern of a potential for an execution difference is non-existent. Nothing is wrong with my answer.

Comment: The concern can't be non-existent ^^ The difference is [very real](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259636/is-this-a-bug-in-files-lines-or-am-i-misunderstanding-something-about-paralle), too. Btw: what makes `Iterable.forEach` terminal?

Comment: @Unihedro Very amusing that you claim "API detail" to justify your appeal to an implementation detail!  Your statement is simply wrong; the `forEach`   method in `Stream` is unrelated to the one in `Iterable`.  The current implementation in the current version of the Oracle JDK happens to use the `Iterable` one, but this is mostly irrelevant, as you cannot count on this staying the same.  You can only rely on the API specification.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I'm going to have to precede my reply with the fact that [the javadocs of `Stream.forEach` says "Performs an action for each element of this stream. \[...\] The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-). A lack of guarantee is not a lack of assurance in using `forEach` in non-parallel streams. zeroflag linked a relevant example on how this may make a difference, but it explicitly uses parallel streams, where Streams as representations of Iterables...

Comment: ... are implemented as Spliterators within StreamSupport that invokes the underlying forEach operation of the Iterable. While the current implementation of `Stream.forEach` can change over time, so does `Iterable.forEach`. That doesn't hit the problem asked at all.

Comment: `Stream.forEach` *does not* call `Iterable.forEach` with the current implementation. This can be proved easily: `new ArrayList<String>(){ @Override public void forEach(Consumer<? super String> c) {
System.out.println("Iterable.forEach"); } }.stream().forEach(x->{});` will *not* print the message…