# how to read File from a particular line till the end of the File in java

Tags: java, java-io

I have this File :

```
 Line1.
 Line2.
 Line3.
 Line4.
```

I want to start reading from the second line (**`Line2`**) till the end of the file.  How can i do this in Java?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Amazing. Do you really need stack overflow to tell you how to implement a counter and how the concept of if/then/else works?

Comment: @JohannisK I will add my code to the question .

Comment: Read from the very beginning and discard the first line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to read the file line by line, but skip the first line, I suggest you do

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("yourfile"))
     .skip(1)
     .forEach(...);
```

---

Note that this solution relies on an API that was added in Java 8 (released March last year), so if you haven't upgraded yet, you may want to do so.

Comment: Not sure if a total beginner will understand that this is Java 8, using streams ... and why it maybe doesnt work at all in his older eclipse. I would at least add some explanations.

Comment: Answer updated. (I usually have future readers in mind when I write my answers, which is why I try to explain "tomorrows" solution.) Right now however, Java 8 has been out for a year, and the fact that he is a beginner tells me that he doesn't have to respect a legacy code base that can't be migrated to Java 8 :-)

Comment: Very nice and clean, much better than what I was thinking of.

Comment: Never you knew you can do that !! :O nice :)

Comment: Don’t forget to [use `forEachOrdered`, not `forEach`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28259636/2711488) if you intend to skip the first line rather than any line.